# wget.sh: line 124: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I got a huge problem that i can't solve. I'm coding an application for my company, you can see that my code is composed by two bash functions. 
When i try to compile i get every time the same error :   `wget.sh: line 124: syntax error: unexpected end of file` n wget.sh is my file. And i don't know why, i searched a lot and it don't seems to be a real syntax error like i fogot a `fi` after a `if`. Furthermore i look at my file and there is no other line after 123...
Help me to solve this please !

```
#!/bin/bash


#----------------------------------------------------ApplicationTaxa----------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------Créateur:Axel Bonnafoux-------------------------------------------------------


#Projet conditions : Avoir le fichier build.Xml dans le dossier pour pouvoir éxecuter le code Java.



# ---------------------------------------------Projet partie 1 : Concaténation (bash)-------------------------------------------- 


Annee=$(date +%Y)
Mois2=$(date +%m)
Mot="init"
Mot2="maj"
Mot3="Facture"

# Creer un dossier Année
if [ ! -d taxa/$Annee  ]
then 
mkdir -p taxa/$Annee
fi
```

I run this without function and its actually working ! Help me to know why

```
 #Fonction concat
 #Concatene les fichiers client récupérés sur serveur ftp
 Concat()
 {
 for Month in $F
 do
    # Créer un dossier Mois
 Mois=$(echo $FILES |cut -d '/' -f4 )
 mkdir -p taxa/$Annee/$Mois 

 # Parcour les fichiers disponibles et les concatene par Mois par client                            
 for Day in $Month'/*'
 do
    for file in $Day'/*'
    do
        filename1=$(echo $file |cut -d '/' -f6 )
        filename2=$(echo $filename1|cut -d '-' -f1|cut -d '_' -f1)

        # Si le fichier n'existe pas, on le créer et on copie son contenu
        if [ ! -e taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.csv ]
        then
            touch taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.csv
            cat  $file >> taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.csv

        # Concatene le nouveau fichier client avec l'ancien
        else 
            cat  $file |sed '1d' >> taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.csv
        fi
    done
done
done}   




#-----------------------------------------Projet partie 2 : Traitement des données (bash&&Java)------------------------------------------

#Fonction traitement
#Execute la partie javascript pour chaque fichier, somme les coûts et le temps passé des appels
Traitement()
{
for FILES2 in $F2
do 
#Récupération du Mois courant
Mois=$(echo $FILES2 |cut -d '/' -f4 )
for D in $FILES2'/*'
do
    #Création d'un fichier Excel par client
    filename1=$(echo $D |cut -d '/' -f6 )
    filename2=$(echo $filename1|cut -d '-' -f1|cut -d '_' -f1)
    touch taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.xls
    java -classpath Taxa2 WriteMatriceFG taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.csv taxa/$Annee/$Mois/$filename2.xls

    #Initialisation d'un tableau de Correspondance à remplir plus tard manuellement
    #Il contient les forfait et prix horaires pour chaque client
    touch TableauCorrespondance_$Mois.xls
    touch TableauCorrespondance_$Mois_2.xls
    java -classpath Taxa2 WriteMatricePrix     TableauCorrespondance_$Mois_2.xls filename2
    cat TableauCorrespondance_$Mois_2.xls >> TableauCorrespondance_$Mois
    rm TableauCorrespondance_$Mois_2.xls

    #Verifie que le nombre de ligne est correct et si le fichier est complet ( qu'il n'y ai pas de trou en somme)
    NF = $(ls *csv  | wc -l)
    nbligne=$(wc -l TableauCorrespondance_$Mois_2.xls|cut -d ' ' -f1)
    Res=java -classpath Taxa2 verification TableauCorrespondance_$Mois.xls
    if [$NF=$((nbligne*3)) && Res]
    then
        #Enfin, on calcule la facture que le client doit régler en fonction du tableau de correspondance qui doit être remplit.         
        java -classpath Taxa2 MatriceTreatment filename2.xls TableauCorrespondance_$Mois.xls
    else
        echo "votre tableau de correspondance nest pas complet"
    fi
done
done}


# récupère les données du serveur ftp si l'on a rien (avec l'option n), récupère seulement les données du mois avec l'option maj et traite seulement les données avec toutes les autres options
if  [ $1 = "$mot" ]     
then
wget -m --ftp-user=********* --ftp-password=********* ftp://ftp-openvno.alphalink.fr/valo/$Annee
F=ftp-openvno.alphalink.fr/valo/$Annee'/*'
Concat
else 
if [ -d taxa/$Annee/$Mois2 ] && [ $1 = "$Mot2" ]
then
    rm -r taxa/$Annee/$Mois2
    wget -m --ftp-user=*********** --ftp-password=******** ftp://ftp-openvno.alphalink.fr/valo/$Annee/$Mois2





F=ftp-openvno.alphalink.fr/valo/$Annee'/*'
    Concat
else 
    F2=taxa/$Annee'/*'
    Traitement
fi
fi
#supprime les fichiers téléchargés devenu obsolète
rm -r ftp-openvno.alphalink.fr
exit 0
```

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question, most of which is probably irrelevant to your problem. If you can reduce the length and provide us with a [mcve] then it will probably be much easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Please run your code through http://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that it reports like the incorrect closing brace on `done}` (the cause of this error you're seeing) and missing spaces around `[` in an `if` statement and plenty of other suggestions

Comment: Hey ! I found the answer thanks to shellsheck.net. To make a great function in shell, it needs to put "{" on a new line ! Thank you so much <3

Comment: Please translate the comments in code to English before posting on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be mostly possible due to incorrect closing of any statements in your script. As mentioned in comments you can paste your script to [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to get some useful reports.

Comment: Hey ! I found the answer thanks to shellsheck.net. To make a great function in shell, it needs to put "{" on a new line ! Thank you so much <3